# Меняю таблицы местами, при этом количество строк неизменно

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Два вопроса:

1. Почему, когда меняю таблицы местами, количество строк у таблицы А неизменно, ведь она (таблица А) заменилась на таблицу с меньшим количеством столбцов ...?
2. Почему alert() срабатывает раньше чем происходит смена мест таблиц, ведь он - alert() прописан после основного кода?

```js
'use strict'
var A = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="a"] table'),
    B = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="b"] table'),
    C = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="c"] table');


document.body.onclick = function() {

  var parentA = A.parentNode,
      parentB = B.parentNode,
      a = parentB.replaceChild(A, B);

  parentA.insertBefore(a, null);

  alert(A.querySelectorAll('tr').length);
}
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 15px 30px 0 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.b-matrix {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 25px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
/*------- [ ] -------*/

.b-matrix_border:before,
.b-matrix_border:after,
.b-matrix__table_border:before,
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #444;
  content: '';
}
.b-matrix_border:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix_border:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/*----- // [ ] // -----*/

.b-matrix__table input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="c">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="a">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="main">
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="b">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Смотрите: вы сохранили в переменную А указатель на конкретный элемент в DOM, на таблицу внутри data-name=a:

```
var A = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="a"] table')
```

Разумеется, теперь всегда, когда вы будете проверять, сколько строк в этой таблице, вы будете получать одинаковый результат (в рамках данного примера, по крайней мере). Вы же не меняете количество строк внутри этой таблицы? Вы меняете эту и какую-то другую таблицы местами. Но они и их целостность и кол-во строк остаются неизменными. Это как спросить "я заменил красное яблоко на зеленое, но почему красное осталось красным?".

В коде, предложенном C.Raf.T вы можете увидеть, что он проверяет кол-во строк не у самой таблицы, как вы, а у блока-родителя, а это уже совершенно другое дело, ведь внутри блока уже другая таблица.

2 - не совсем так. Алерт срабатывает как и положено по коду - позже смены таблиц. Но раньше *отрисовки* изменений на странице. Если вы посмотрите в DevTools на код страницы, вы увидите, что на момент вызова алерт таблицы уже переместились. Но браузер не сразу отрисовывает изменения. Когда он это делает -- очень обширная тема для изучения, в данном случае важно то, что он делает это чуть позже, чем происходят непосредственные изменения в DOM.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.

Comment: Хотя вообще странно, что не работает такой вариант - alert(parentA.querySelectorAll('tr').length);

Comment: И такой - A.parentNode.querySelectorAll('tr').length;

Comment: А он почти не отличается от вашего первого. Родитель же у таблицы тоже меняется постоянно. Таблица была в блоке "а", здесь вызов A.parentNode возвращает родителя "а". Вы перемещаете таблицу в блок "б", и теперь вызов A.parentNode уже возвращает "б". И так и там через родителя вы, опять же, узнаете сколько строк в одной и той же таблице А, пусть она и в разных местах.

Comment: Вот если на базовом этапе, один раз, запомнить родителей, т.е. сохранить в переменные ссылки на родителей каждой таблицы, и не перезаписывать эти переменные при клике, тогда результат будет такой, как вы ожидаете. Т.е. если вынести var parentA = *** из функции обработчика клика.

Comment: Понял вас, Иван, еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

На счет почему срабатывает раньше не знаю, но если в `alert` проверять по родителю `div`:

```
alert(document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="a"]').querySelectorAll('tr').length);
```

```js
'use strict'
var A = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="a"] table'),
    B = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="b"] table'),
    C = document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="c"] table');


document.body.onclick = function() {

  var parentA = A.parentNode,
      parentB = B.parentNode,
      a = parentB.replaceChild(A, B);

  parentA.insertBefore(a, null);

  alert(document.querySelector('.b-matrix[data-name="a"]').querySelectorAll('tr').length);
}
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 15px 30px 0 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.b-matrix {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 25px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
/*------- [ ] -------*/

.b-matrix_border:before,
.b-matrix_border:after,
.b-matrix__table_border:before,
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #444;
  content: '';
}
.b-matrix_border:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix_border:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:before {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.b-matrix__table_border:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/*----- // [ ] // -----*/

.b-matrix__table input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="c">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" disabled />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="a">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="main">
  <div class="b-matrix b-matrix_border" data-name="b">
    <table class="b-matrix__table b-matrix__table_border">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```